# Hide text in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

Can I only show the code in a google colab notebook?

I would like to hide all the additional text and that stuff.

[image]

For example, in this case i would like to hide "Hyperparamters" and see the code joined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the cell and select the 'Hide form' menu.

[image]